# Updating firmware for BB10 issue

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-10

I updated my BB10 DEV Alpha device for a firmware update on 10.2.For that I download the Dev Alpha B 10.2 from this url https://developer.blackberry.com/blackberry10devalpha/devalpha_update.html after which updated the device with the downloader as per the instructions given after the firmware updated my device didnt boot and became dead can anyone help me in this issue .

I have a BB10 DEV ALPHA A device.

Comment: Dev alpha A isn't getting 10.2. Sorry. You can't get it work

Answer (score 1):

Dev Alpha B update doesn't work for Dev Alpha as per I know. I have also tried to upgrade, but as it didn't worked I downgraded it to previous version.

Also, this is mentioned on BB Website.

> Note: You may attempt to load the latest Dev Alpha B update onto your Dev Alpha A, however the The Dev Alpha A is no longer officially supported as of 10.1.0.1485. If you encounter any issues please downgrade back to 10.0.10.263 using the Autoloader method. You can download the old 10.0.10.263 Autoloader here.

https://developer.blackberry.com/blackberry10devalphas/update/

Comment: Yeah I tried even downgrading the version but my phone isnt rebooting after the firmware update :( can anyone help me on this

Comment: Try to hold power button continuously for 30 seconds or little more. It will boot your device up with Dev Alpha Splash.

Comment: You bricked it, i think there was a debricking method. Contact BlackBerry, but if I were you I'd go ahead and buy an actual device.

Comment: If you say I have bricked it can anyone tell me on how to unbrick it

Comment: I even tried by connecting it to Blackberry desktop software but it say no updates available now . Anyone please help me sort out this issue please :(

Comment: I somehow solved it myself I tried downgrading the os to 10.1 and it started working .Thanks everyone :) .I somehow now got my dev alpha work .